# PostgreSql - Cast to cidr during database migration

Tags: postgresql, varchar, postgresql-9.6, cidr, pgadmin-4

I'm french. So, sorry for my mistakes !

I'm doing a database migration on PostgreSql 9.6 via pgAdmin4 and in the first one there's a CHARACTER VARYING type field and in the other it's a CIDR type field.
I use this command :

```
INSERT INTO ip.cidr (cid_id, cid_res_id, cid_cidr)
SELECT a, b, network(c) FROM dblink('host=xxx user=xxx password=xxx dbname=xxx', 'SELECT ipp_id, res_id, ipp_ipcidr FROM public.ipplage')
AS x(a integer, b integer, c cidr)
```

but it doesn't work !
This is the error :

> ERREUR:  invalid cidr value : « 10.26.3.0/23 »
>   DETAIL:  The value has bits positioned to the right of the mask.
>   ********** Error **********
>   ERREUR: invalid cidr value : « 10.26.3.0/23 »
>   SQL state: 22P02
>   Detail: The value has bits positioned to the right of the mask.

*errors are in french. I translated it myself*

I tried to cast varchar to cidr  but it doesn't work ! same eror !
I searched everywhere to know how to cast this f*****g CHARACTER VARYING to CIDR type but no result ! Please !!! Help me ! :(

Comment: the "g" in Postgres isnt capitalized.

Comment: oh thanks ! but it's not realy my problem :D

Comment: I know but have to solve that before start reading :P

Comment: I did some testing and my guess the problem is on the data you get from the db_link. can you test your query but hardcode the ip address? like this: `SELECT ipp_id, res_id, '10.26.3.0/23' as ipp_ipcidr FROM public.ipplage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `10.26.3.0/23` is not the address of the network. `10.26.2.0/23` is.

So you have two options, it depends on what infos do you want to keep :

```
INSERT INTO ip.cidr (cid_id, cid_res_id, cid_cidr)
SELECT a, b, network(c) FROM dblink('host=xxx user=xxx password=xxx dbname=xxx', 'SELECT ipp_id, res_id, ipp_ipcidr::inet::cidr FROM public.ipplage')
AS x(a integer, b integer, c cidr)
```

This cast the network address to inet and then, find the network address of the inet.

Or, if you want to keep your address :

```
INSERT INTO ip.cidr (cid_id, cid_res_id, cid_cidr)
SELECT a, b, network(c) FROM dblink('host=xxx user=xxx password=xxx dbname=xxx', 'SELECT ipp_id, res_id, ipp_ipcidr FROM public.ipplage')
AS x(a integer, b integer, c inet)
```

If you want more infos : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-net-types.html

EDIT: by the way, if you want your error in plain english and not in french (I'm french and experiencing the same issue ;-) You can comment out this lines in the `postgresql.conf`:

```
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.french'
```

Comment: Interesting. I tough the problem was the ip address but when test it was autocorrected and didnt throw any error. http://rextester.com/QXFG14627